# MySQL group replication configuration issue

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, mysql-replication

I am trying to create an instance in one AWS region that would be a group replica of an instance in a different region(both are database servers). I followed the below link to do this.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-mysql-group-replication-on-ubuntu-16-04

But, when I modify the my.cnf file(as [server1's config image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGh0y.jpg) and [server2's config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmVlH.jpg) image) and restart mysql, I get the following errors in the mysql's error log:
2018-01-31T12:33:21.855687Z 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address
2018-01-31T12:33:21.855690Z 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 33061 ?
2018-01-31T12:33:21.855699Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

When I changed the config to the default one and then start mysql, I am able to grep mysql using  $sudo netstat -lntp|grep 3306.

Can anyone tell me how to setup a mysql group replication?

Comment: provide this /var/log/mysql/error.log please

Comment: Does "Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address" and "Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?" tell you nothing??

Comment: You can't run several apps binding the same port.

Comment: I've changed one of them to 33061. But that did not fix this.

Comment: Fix what? Did you check you mysql error.log for new messages? Did you stop all your mysql instances before restart them? Did you check all application binding at 3306 with netstat -lntp|grep 3306? We can't chat using comments, sorry. Edit your question, add useful info: your steps, error logs, configs..etc

Comment: You are using public IP addresses for this?  Unjustifiable.  Peer your VPCs.

Comment: I am using public IP addresses and VPC Peering is not available in my region